# Install gems in a Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rakefile

I've searched around the Internet, what is the syntax for installing a gem in a rakefile? the only way I've been able to is to skirt around the issue and use a exec() function e.g.

```
cmd = "gem install geoip"
exec(cmd)
```

There has to be a better way for this. 
    gems:install
Does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 2):

Bundler is used to download gems. Rake is just used to run tasks with the Ruby code itself

You would create a `Gemfile`, give it a source like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

and add the gems you want like this

```
gem 'rails'
```

then run `bundle` in the directiory with the `Gemfile` and it gets all of the gems you need.

Comment: I want to add a gem from a private geminabox server, but Gemfile doesn't seem to allow the username:password@geminabox.server.com format for https :-(

Comment: Try asking a new question. This one is over 2 years old